# Access current object from within itself

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)
>   [Can you call data from it's own json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264328/can-you-call-data-from-its-own-json-object)

I'm creating an object like this:

```
var lines = {
    all: [ /* Array */ ],
    current: this.all[1]
}
```

However the `current: this.all[1]` returns `undefined`. I know full well that I can create the  `current` property like this:

```
var lines = {
    all: [ /* Array */ ]
}
lines.current = lines.all[1];
```

But I think this is quite messy, especially when creating multiple properties that need to reference their own object.

I've tried using both

- `current: this.all[1]` (returns `undefined`) and
- `current: lines.all[1]` (says `lines` doesn't exist)

How can I reference properties of the object I'm currently "in"? For instance, in my first example `lines.current` would be assigned the second element from `lines.all`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172111/can-i-alias-a-key-in-an-object-literal/8172171#8172171

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just one other solution than the one you posted:

```
var lines = new function() {
    this.all = [ /* Array */ ];
    this.current = this.all[1];
};
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a "cleaner" solution, but I guess there isn't. I could've used a getter function, but that's even messier and doesn't lend well to debugging with `console.log()`.

Comment: this i think is slightly different from the question as lines in this case is closer to class in OOP than to object

Comment: @Parv I'm not too bothered really; this solution returns an object which is all I'm worried about.

Answer (score 0):

because current is probably just a `getter`
you should according to some conventions change the name to `getCurrent()` as the top element in the array might change
and change your code to something like this.

```
var lines = {
    all: [ /* Array */ ],
    getCurrent: function(){return this.all[1];}
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution in that it keeps everything inside the object, however it doesn't debug that well with `console.log()`, so I've decided to use `new function()` instead.